# laravel querying database not producing expected results

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to execute this sql query using laravel query builder.

```
SELECT leagues.id, leagues.name, countries.name
FROM leagues
INNER JOIN countries ON leagues.country = countries.id
```

I have the following Laravel query...

```
$leagueinfo = DB::table('leagues')
        ->join('countries','leagues.country', '=', 'countries.id')
        ->select('leagues.id', 'leagues.name', 'countries.name')
        ->get();
```

but when I print_r($leagueinfo) out to the screen I get this...

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => England ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => Spain ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [name] => Italy ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [name] => Austria ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [name] => Germany ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [name] => England ) )
```

.. which looks like it's picking up my countries only.

The sql query returns the correct results... the league.id, league.name and the countries.name

Would anyone have any suggestions why the information is not coming through, please?
Thanks.

DS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your result set, you actually have the ID as well. What's happening is you're overwriting your column name in the result set since two fields are both "name". Try the following instead:

```
$leagueinfo = DB::table('leagues')
    ->join('countries','leagues.country', '=', 'countries.id')
    ->select('leagues.id', 'leagues.name as league', 'countries.name as country')
    ->get();
```

Comment: perfect. thanks very much. i'll know to rename them next time. seems obvious when you point it out! DS